# Removing a row from a table using a button through JS?

Tags: javascript

I am making an expense App for a personal project.

I am trying to add a 'x' button to delete the row of data that has been added to the table. I have managed to add the button and it removes the row, however, when I go to add another row I get: 'the index provided (8) is greater than the number of rows in the table (2).' error
(the number changes depending on how many times i click 'x').

```js
var entry = document.getElementById("entry");
entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

var row = 1;

function displayDetails() {
  var item = document.getElementById("item").value;
  var date = document.getElementById("date").value;
  var cost = document.getElementById("cost").value;

  if (!item || !date || !cost) {
    alert("Please fill in all the boxes!");
    return;
  }

  var display = document.getElementById("display");

  var newRow = display.insertRow(row);

  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = item;
  cell2.innerHTML = date;
  cell3.innerHTML = cost;
  cell4.innerHTML = "<button>X</button>";

  cell4.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("display").deleteRow(-1);
  });

  row++;
}
```

```html
<div class="formContainer">
  <label for="item">Item</label>
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item" id="item" />

  <label for="date">Date</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />

  <label for="cost">Cost</label>
  <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="cost" id="cost" />
</div>
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <button id="entry">Submit Expense</button>
  <button id="clear" onclick="window.location.reload()">Clear List</button>
</div>
<div class="tableContainer">
  <table id="display">
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

I have tried a number of different ways to stop this from happening but I get different errors. I'm not quite sure how to approach this as I am fairly new to JS.

any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 4):

The issue is because you need to decrement the row count when you delete the row:

```js
cell4.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
  document.getElementById("display").deleteRow(-1);
  row--;
});
```

```js
const entry = document.querySelector("#entry");
entry.addEventListener("click", displayDetails);

const display = document.querySelector("#display");

function displayDetails() {
  const item = document.querySelector("#item").value;
  const date = document.querySelector("#date").value;
  const cost = document.querySelector("#cost").value;

  if (!item || !date || !cost) {
    alert("Please fill in all the boxes!");
    return;
  }

  var newRow = display.insertRow();
  var cell1 = newRow.insertCell(0);
  var cell2 = newRow.insertCell(1);
  var cell3 = newRow.insertCell(2);
  var cell4 = newRow.insertCell(3);

  cell1.innerHTML = item;
  cell2.innerHTML = date;
  cell3.innerHTML = cost;
  cell4.innerHTML = "<button>X</button>";

  cell4.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
    document.getElementById("display").deleteRow(-1);
    row--;
  });

  row++;
}
```

```html
<div class="formContainer">
  <label for="item">Item</label>
  <input type="text" name="item" placeholder="Item" id="item" />

  <label for="date">Date</label>
  <input type="date" name="date" id="date" />

  <label for="cost">Cost</label>
  <input type="text" name="cost" placeholder="cost" id="cost" />
</div>
<div class="buttonContainer">
  <button id="entry">Submit Expense</button>
  <button id="clear" onclick="window.location.reload()">Clear List</button>
</div>
<div class="tableContainer">
  <table id="display">
    <tr>
      <th>Item</th>
      <th>Date</th>
      <th>Cost</th>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! I thought it may have been something with the row count because of the error, but i couldnt get my head around it